# building a scanner . Identifying the tokens

Tags: c, compiler-construction, token, tokenize, lexical

I need to perform tokenization as a part of creating a Scanner.

I want to scan Integers and real numbers as two different kinds of tokens. For example if i have a token 1.0 .

How can i classify it as integer or a real number.

Comment: To increase the chances of this question getting seen by users able to answer, and so users know what your talking about, [edit] the question and add an applicable language tag. Also, to conform to [so] guidelines, you should show how you've tried to solve this problem yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Use a regex to recognize both floats and integers (see http://www.regular-expressions.info/floatingpoint.html), then classify them as integers if they do not contain a decimal point or an exponent.

Comment: In c language can a character be treated as an integer token?

Comment: Here 1.0 is an integer , and it has a decimal point . How can i tokenize it as an integer?

Comment: I suppose you could explicitly recognize a fractional part consisting only of zeros, but all languages I know of (certainly C) would treat 1.0 as a float, not an int.